# Angular - similar Directives

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my application I need to use few layouts of progress bar:
One with label bellow the bar, one with 3 labels to the right of the bar to name just two.
There should be some horizontal bars and vertical bars.

Though to use the Angular Bootstrap progress bar directive.

Any thoughts how to implement?
Is the Bootstrap directive flexible, by passing parameters, to support all the above requirements?
Maybe (if possible...) to extend the basic directive to few types of progress bar directives?

Any thought / idea / example / ... will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/cvxuJ check this

Answer (score 0):

You can use twitterbootstrap progress bars. They have implemented different types of progress bars acc to your need you can tailor them.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress

Comment: Twitterbootstrap bars is what I'm trying to work with.   the issue is how to implement few "appearances" of it:   one vertical bar with text on the bottom, one vertical bar with 3 texts, one bellow the other to the right of the bar, one horizontal bar with text to its right, and more...

Comment: By text you mean headings for progress bars? or their completion value/percentage?
Appearances? Means its placement? Vertical and horizontal?

Comment: Frankly never tried vertical progress bar. I think you apply transformation on it.
Percentage of completion can be shown by giving value to width attribute of style.
You can implement as many different progress bars. But there are no directives there are classes which you can use given by Bootstrap and give them roles. This is some basic HTML they are using along with CSS. Angular bootstrap directive is kind of a different thing.

Comment: Angularui Bootstrap is different from simple twitterBootstrap js. Angular UI bootstrap is built on top of twitter bootstrap but in angular code and gives you directives to implement bootstrap functionalities like progress bars, on the other hand twitterbootstrap only provides classes(no directives) to do same task.

Comment: Text could be: "Completion:XY%". it can't be inside the bar (not enough space). Some bars will show percentage, some will show actual value (in the labels near the bars).  Appearance: Vertical or Horizontal, header text / footer text (maybe both) / some text (with values) to the right of the bars.     there is no question about the "inner" bar itself. the question is about the elements around it. the basic bar component/directive does not support any surrounding texts. as I have few bars of each type - I thought to create directive for each type, that will "wrap" the basic progress bar itself.

Comment: For completion:xy% you can  hide basic inside value in bar and can show outside as a label as your percentage value must be coming from backend. It is shown in example how to show or not show percentage inside bar. e.g. : "Remove the <span> with .sr-only class from within the progress bar to show a visible percentage."

Appearance in bootstrap is basically DIVs elements with classes not directives. So transformation will be applicable to them. Little tweaking them will get you what you desire. 

Finally if you want more customization use twitter bootstrap not angular UI as angularUi.